# Updating pinned columns styles based on scroll events in center body

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to update my pinned columns styles whenever they are "overlapping" the centered display column group. For the left pinned column, this is straightforward, simply check onBodyScroll event `e.left > 0`. For the right pinned column, this is trickier, as I see no clear way of determining the right offset via ag-grid api/columnApi. I suppose refs could be used here, or reaching into private values on the `ColumnModel` , but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way, possibly using ag-grid functions?

Below is a example of how it could be done, but it is using private values on the `ColumnModel`.

```js
  //...
  const [leftPinnedOverlaying, setLeftPinnedOverlaying] = useState(false);
  const [rightPinnedOverlaying, setRightPinnedOverlaying] = useState(true);
  const hasMounted = useRef(false);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
      <pre>
      {JSON.stringify({leftPinnedOverlaying,rightPinnedOverlaying})}
      </pre>

      <div className="example-wrapper">        
        <div
          id="myGrid"
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
          className="ag-theme-alpine"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
            debug={true}
            rowData={rowData}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            onBodyScroll={(e)=> {
              // first pass seems to pass non-ideal state
              if(!hasMounted.current) {
                hasMounted.current=true
                return
              }
              setLeftPinnedOverlaying(e.left > 0);
              const columnModel = e.columnApi.columnModel;
              // Get around these properties being private by indexing via array
              const scrollWidth = columnModel["scrollWidth"] || 0;
              const bodyWidth = columnModel["bodyWidth"] || 0;

              setRightPinnedOverlaying((e.left+scrollWidth) < bodyWidth)

            }}
          >
            <AgGridColumn
              headerName="Athlete"
              field="athlete"
              width={150}
              pinned="left"
              cellStyle={leftPinnedOverlaying ? {backgroundColor: 'blue'}:{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
            />
// ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>)
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PbPizespgodTZMRg

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear to me what has to overlap, but I will assume that some condition has to be met.

I had a look at your code and noticed that you are using the old syntax for declaring column definitions in react.
So I hope you don't mind that my ADHD mind had to change this :)

Also, regarding header names - unless you are planning to have a header name different from your field, you do not need to provide a column header property.

In regards to meeting a condition for your pinned row styling, you can pass a **callback to the** **cellStyle**, it receives params from the grid, including rowNode (where the grid keeps rows state information) and row data object (all the values in the row).

Please note there is also a **rowPinned** property in the row object that you can use to identify - the left, right, top and bottom pinned rows.
link to docs - React Data Grid: Row Object (aka Row Node) - https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-object/

I added some random conditions in the cellStyles.
please see the code examples below.

```
const columnDefs = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        field: 'athlete',
        width: 150,
        pinned: 'left',
        cellStyle: (params) =>
          params.value.includes('el')
            ? { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
            : { backgroundColor: 'white' },
      },
      { field: 'country', width: 150 },
      { field: 'year', width: 90 },
      { field: 'date', width: 110 },
      { field: 'sport', width: 150 },
      { field: 'gold', width: 100 },
      { field: 'silver', width: 100 },
      { field: 'bronze', width: 100 },
      {
        field: 'total',
        width: 100,
        pinned: 'right',
        cellStyle: (params) =>
          params.rowIndex % 2 == 0
            ? { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
            : { backgroundColor: 'white' },
      },
    ],
    []
  );
```

and here is the grid component.

```
  <AgGridReact
    defaultColDef={{ resizable: true }}
    rowData={rowData}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
  ></AgGridReact>
```

Here is **your code example updated**: https://plnkr.co/edit/n3Rum6YeOqHOngki